# Passing default params to rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple form like:

```
= form_tag history_path(params), :method => :get do
  = radio_button_tag :history_id, @history.id, true
  History
  %br

  = submit_tag "Get History", class: "btn generate"
```

Now, **params** has some extra info like `{visit_id: 1, company_id: 32}`

Even when I inspect the form I see the action as:

```
<form action="/history?visit_id=1&company_id=32" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
```

But, upon clicking submit, the **params** are never passed, I only get the following **params** passed (in server log):

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "history_id"=>"939", "commit"=>"Get History"}
```

**EDIT**

I'm aware that I can add them to `hidden_field_tag`, but the params can be many and I can't keep on adding hidden fields. So, I need to understand why the above way isn't working.

Comment: You can add them to the form as hidden field objects. Make sure you allow them to pass your strong parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a rails problem, it's just html, because your form has the get method, it will replace all get variables that you have on the url action and let just the ones that are on the form. 
you can combine this, sending get variables in the url, but with the form as post, not on get. 
in this case then you have 2 options, use the solution that @Deepak Mahakale sent, or change your form to post, and make the respective changes on the controller and routes.

Comment: This is a good explanation, also `GET` request don't have a body.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding them as [**`hidden_field_tag`**](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag)

```
= form_tag history_path(params), :method => :get do
  = hidden_field_tag :visit_id, 1
  = hidden_field_tag :company_id, 32
  = radio_button_tag :history_id, @history.id, true
  History
  %br

  = submit_tag "Get History", class: "btn generate"
```

And now you will receive the data in params as

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "history_id"=>"939", "visit_id" => "1", "company_id" => "32", "commit"=>"Get History"}
```

Comment: I'm sure this would work, but the **params** can be many and I can't keep on adding hidden fields. I better need to understand why my way doesn't work